# new mysqli - Why error message will display

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to check if accessing mysql is possible or not.

I don't wont to have an error message, only true/false if the connection is ready or not.

I tried to do it with this :

```
$appDB = new mysqli($data[0]['MYSQL']['HOST'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['BENUTZER'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['PW'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['TABELLE']);
  if ($appDB->connect_error) 
  { $res['code']=FALSE; } 
  else 
  { 
    $appDB -> close();
    $res['code']=TRUE; 
  }
```

But always a error message will come up - how can i prevent this message from showing ?

```
"<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Access denied for user ''
@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /is/htdocs/...mypath
.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /is/htdocs...mypath.myfile.php(33): mysqli-&gt;mysqli('', ''
, '', '')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/is/htdocs/wp1076647_373QG1K1B0/butobo/module/4/code/cms_checkcon.php</b> on line <b>33
</b><br />"
```

Comment: Your user variable is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "catch" this fatal exception via a try/catch statement. This allows you to handle the fatal error and then instead of your script crashing due to it, you can output an error message and exit instead :D

PHP Exceptions: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

I hope this helps.

```
try
{
    $appDB = new mysqli($data[0]['MYSQL']['HOST'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['BENUTZER'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['PW'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['TABELLE']);
      if ($appDB->connect_error) 
      { $res['code']=FALSE; } 
      else 
      { 
        $appDB -> close();
        $res['code']=TRUE; 
      }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    exit;
}
```

This will change the ERROR to a WARNING, which will not break your script. From there, if you want to hide everything EXCEPT fatal errors, you can use this line of PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

Comment: i get this errormessage by using your code "<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password
: NO) in <b>/is/htdocs/...mypathandfile.php</b> on line <b>40<
/b><br />
{"code":false}"

Comment: Additional i've the same problem if i try it with ftp, there we also display errors - maybe its a other kind of pre-setting of php or something else?

Comment: @newbieRB Notice, that is a warning now, not a fatal error as the original post suggests :D On a production environment, you should probably set the PHP error log level to E_ERROR by running this line of PHP: error_reporting(E_ERROR);

Comment: error_reporting(E_ERROR); thats was the simple think i need :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Error message would display because your PHP is configured to do so. To make it not display, simply configure it like

```
ini_set('display_errors', "0");
```

However, this code also stops the execution. It order to prevent it, you have to catch the exception. So it should be like

```
try {
    $appDB = new mysqli($data[0]['MYSQL']['HOST'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['BENUTZER'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['PW'], $data[0]['MYSQL']['TABELLE']);
    $res['code']=TRUE; 
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    error_log($e);
    $res['code']=FALSE;
}
```

while setting `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` is rather stupid as it will prevent you from seeing all other errors

Comment: Not only is this essentially the same answer as the one above, "setting error_reporting(E_ERROR); is rather stupid" is a stupid statement. It prevents him from seeing everything < E_ERROR. He can still see fatal errors just fine. Unlike this answer, which literally disables all error output.

Comment: just like many fellow PHP users, you imagine yourself the only user of your site. But the problem is, sometimes it goes *live*, and then it become impossible to sit behind every user's screen and "watch" errors :) So, surprisingly, any mature site in the world prevents users from seeing raw error output.

Comment: Some of us write PHP in a framework that is smart enough to use output buffering. I suppose we can't all be in the uppermost echelons of PHP developers, as you seem to think you are, but maybe you could try making your application not output the errors, instead of making PHP do it.

Comment: your fantasies, though really amusing, are hardly plausible. As far as I concerned, there are no frameworks exist that let errors to be spat right into site design, then buffered and then hunted down with some intricate parsing :)

Comment: None of that was a fantasy, this is real life and those are real functions. That really works and if you happen to have an IDE installed, maybe you should try to open your mind to new ideas. I used to use ini_set('display_errors', "0") until I learned that application errors should be handled by the application. I just wanted to explain the difference, cheers.